# image not save in data base (Laraval 8)

Tags: database, laravel, image

when I load an image via my form, the latter registers well in the / public storage but not in the database.
here is my recording function in ProduitController.

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    
    $request->validate([
        'nom_produit' => 'required|min:4',
        'prix_produit' => 'required|min:0.0',
        'quantite_produit' => 'required|min:0.0',
        'description_produit' => 'required|min:10',
        'lieu_produit' => 'required|min:2',
        'like_produit' => 'required|min:0.0',
        'etat_produit' => 'required|min:0.0',
        'vedette_produit' => 'required|min:0.0',
        'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id',
        'categorie_id' => 'required|exists:categories,id',
        'image_produit'=>  'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|required'
    ]);
    
    $requestData = $request->all();
    
    if ($request->hasfile('image_produit')) {
        $image_produit = $request->file('image_produit');

         $image_produit= $image_produit->getClientOriginalName();
         
         //$path = $image_produit->storeAs('uploads\produit', $image_produit, 'public');
         $path =$request->file('image_produit')->storeAs('uploads\produit', $image_produit, 'public');

     }
```

Comment: why are you loading image in database only save the name

Answer (score 0):

after save the image in public folder then take a file name in variable

```
$file_name = uniqid().".".$request->file('image_produit')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

and then save in the db.

```
Model::create(['image_produit' => $file_name]);
```